# HSTS in iFrame src

Tags: html, ssl, iframe, ssl-certificate

I'm building an app that needs to serve websites in an iframe. Since the websites are decided by the user, they usually enter only the domain name, like google.com, or facebook.com. To render the website in an iframe i need to add http:// to this (I can't add https://, since the website may not be served over ssl which will cause it to not render at all.)

For this reason, I am forced to not use ssl on my website, since due to the mixed content policy, I can't add iframes that request http. I wish to know if there's a way to force hsts in the iframe src. For example, if I request http://example.org, the iframe will automatically render https://example.org (since it exists.)

Comment: Can you just alter the user input to change the URL to be HTTPS before you give it to the iFrame?

Comment: @Goose yes I can, but if a website is served over http and not https, it won't load at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS doesn't allow you to serve HTTP content. All content on the page must be a secure connection, including iFrame. This is browser standard so there's no work around to be had. Either your page has to be HTTP or the iFrame has to be HTTPS.